# Speed-up animation render which uses a movie texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, performance

I have many rectangles which display a movie clip, each starting at different points (offset) in the movie.  During animation render, the info area shows:

> Loading texture-movie.mp4@1234

`1234` is the frame number for a particular rectangle.  This message displays about 5 times for all the rectangles that display the movie, each taking about 5 seconds for a total of 25 seconds per frame.

Is there a way to speed-up this part of the render process?

Comment: Sounds like a *decoding* issue. You could try using an image sequence of png's instead.

Comment: and, are you sure the video file resolution is not way too high for the scope of being visualized in a (supposedly, since there are many) small frame in you animation?

Comment: Both good comments and things I've considered.  I'll work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from poor and m.ardito.  Using an image sequence instead of a video clip (in this case an mp4) is the best.  Loading each frame (a particular image) took less than 1 second vs 5 seconds with the video.

If you can't use an image sequence for some reason, reducing the video resolution was also helpful, but not near as much and I had to reduce it a lot more than I wanted.

Another performance tweek was to disable "Cache BVH" under the Performance section of the Render tab.  I'm not clear on how this works but it only slowed down my render (about 10 secs/frame).